# Managing kidney disease in dogs?

Tags: dogs, health, medicines, diseases

I've a 9 yrs old GSD female. She has been suffering from kidney disease since last couple of months. Medication is going on. But her physical condition is getting bad. Is there any way that I can give her healthy life back?

BUN = 34.2 mg/dl
Creatinine = 2.95 mg/dl
Glucose = 76 mg/dl

Comment: She passed away after fighting the battle on last Tuesday evening.

Comment: If you want, there are several grief groups on Facebook and other places, I'm sure.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot reverse kidney disease, it will only go downhill from here. There are ways to slow the progress of the disease such as a change in diet prescribed by your veterinarian, Aventi KP, Epakitin and lots of water intake (Canned food, add water to diet, Subcutaneous fluids).

**Any medications/supplements you use should be prescribed/discussed with your veterinarian.**

I'm sure if you call your clinic they can go into more details with you and guide you better as they know her history and what stage she is at.

Comment: Chronic kidney disease is usually progressive, but sometimes if the inciting cause of the kidney disease is removed, kidney function can recover. Certainly the azotemia may improve with appropriate therapy. I would therefore amend your first sentence to something along the lines of "Unfortunately *chronic* kidney disease is *usually* irreversible and progressive."

Comment: Kidney disease is fatal, you cannot recover kidneys. You may be thinking of liver disease. Or if the kidney was damaged from a blockage then once the cause was fixed it wouldn't continue to spiral downwards. Disease is irreversible.

Comment: No, **all** kidney disease is not fatal. With acute kidney injury leading to tubular damage, the tubules are capable of repairing themselves in some cases. With chronic kidney disease, if nephrons are destroyed then you are correct, the kidneys cannot make new nephrons. Other than this point I agree with your answer and would be happy to upvote it.

Comment: Yes which is what I suspect he's saying - that he has kidney disease and not injury lol I think we're both saying the same thing ha.